# How can I override to __tostring of a metatable in a Lua class?

Tags: lua, tostring

I have this class:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local Die = {}

function Die.new(side)
  if side ~= 4 or side ~= 6 or side ~= 8 or side ~= 10 or side ~= 12 or side ~= 10 or side ~= 100 then
    side = 6
  end
  ran = math.random(side)       -- had to get the value before placing in table
  local self = { numSides = side, currentSide = ran}

  local getValue = function(self)
    return self.currentSide
  end

  local roll = function(self)
    self.currentSide = math.random(self.numSides)
  end

  local __tostring = function(self) 
    return "Die[sides: "..self.numSides..", current value: "..self.currentSide.."]" 
  end

  return {
    numSides = self.numSides,
    currentSide = self.currentSide,
    getValue = getValue,
    roll = roll,
    __tostring = __tostring
  }
end

return Die
```

My goal is when I use the line `print(dieOne)`, for example, is to have the `__tostring` print out the data. Currently, my `__tostring` doesn't work, but I'm pretty sure I'm trying to do this the wrong way.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__tostring` entry must exist in the metatable of every instance you return from `Die.new`. Currently, you're only storing it as an ordinary entry. Here's how you can ensure it's correctly saved in each associated metatable:

```
function Die.new(side)
  -- as before...

  -- setup the metatable
  local mt = {
    __tostring = __tostring
  }

  return setmetatable({
    numSides = self.numSides,
    currentSide = self.currentSide,
    getValue = getValue,
    roll = roll,
  }, mt)
end
```

Here, we leverage the fact that `setmetatable` not only does what its name suggests but also returns the first function argument.

Note that there is no need to call the function itself `__tostring`. Only the metatable key must be `"__tostring"`.

Comment: Hey again lol,  Is `mt` inside the new function or is that on the outside?

Comment: It's inside the function `Die.new`.